# Can I set relative path for execution in ant build script?

Tags: java, ant

I have the following line in my ant script

```
exec executable="$"c:\devTools\Tool.exe" failonerror="true" /exec
```

I want to give the relative path of Tool.exe, instead of the absolute.
Can I do it? How?

Thanks!!

Comment: please provide more information...

Comment: This might help - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html.

Comment: I don't think this is possible since the Ant task works from where the build.xml file resides. If the Tool.exe executable resides in the same folder as the build.xml, then you can ignore the absolute path and just type the executable's filename. Maybe, you can append the path of the executable into the Windows environment variable `PATH`.  By doing this, you can call the executable by its filename only from any folder. Similarly, you can do the same in the build.xml.

Comment: i change it to <property name="executable-full-path"
            location="../relative/path/to/executable"/>
  <exec executable="${executable-full-path}" ... and it works to me

Answer (score 1):

Relative to what?  You can find the directory where current build.xml is.

```
 <project name="projectname" default="runtests" basedir=".">
  ..
 <dirname property="my.projectname.basedir" file="${ant.file.projectname}"/>
```

Then use my.projectname.basedir to another location.

Comment: simply use ${user.dir} for directory of build.xml

Comment: @Rebse: user.dir=>User's current working directory(when JVm starts).

Comment: ..which is the directory ant is started from.

Comment: @Rebse: That is makes it unpredictable.  For example calling same build xml from different directories will give different values. My solution works with somewhat fixed base- the actual location of the build file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the optional `${basedir}` attribute which is '.' by default, means the directory
 your ant script resides. Then put your executable in a path relativ to `${basedir}`
If your basedir attribute is set to another path, the property `${user.dir}` holds the directory
 where your ant script resides.
also use `<echoproperties/>` to see what properties are set by default.

Answer (score 0):

my environment paths are usually set and I overcame this problem using the following code:

```
<exec dir="" executable="program.exe" searchpath="true" >
```

The parameter searchpath enables resolving the location of executable.